# ASP.NET Core API with localized strings

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

We have an ASP.NET Core API. There are no views as again this is a simple API. We have strings in resource files(by culture) and we want each user to get the correct resource (in each API request we have a language name parameter). Also we like to use strongly typed resources in the code. What is the best way to do it? if i simply set the thread UI culture to be the culture from the user it works fine until there is an 'await' in the code(i assume that a different thread kicks in)

Comment: have you read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.0 ?

Comment: @SergeyM yes. I still don't understand how to do it with a resource file with auto generated code property. (strongly typed resources)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot check this on my side but what about the second answer in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976455/how-to-get-resource-strings-in-strongly-typed-way-in-asp-net-core